# как вывести конечное значение из счетчика

Tags: javascript

я делаю счетчик количества продуктов, конечное число которого находится в глобальной переменной sum.
Объект товара я вывожу из бд, которые я парсю в переменную pack.
Кнопки товара:

```
    var sum=1;

        function goodsOut(data){
                if(data!=0){
                    var pack=JSON.parse(data);
                    console.log(pack);
                    var out="";    
             out+=`<div class="val-min" data-id="${pack.id}"><i class="fas fa-minus"></i></div>`;
                     out+=`<div class="val"><span>${sum}</span></div>`;
                     out+=`<div class="val-plus" data-id="${pack.id}" ><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></div>`; 
      }
    $('.goods-out').html(out);
    $('.val-plus').on('click', plusGoods);
    $('.val-min').on('click',minusGoods);
  }

function plusGoods(){
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    sum++;
    console.log(sum);
}

function minusGoods(){
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    sum--;
    console.log(sum);
}
```

При загрузке страницы отображается значение глобальной переменной sum, которое равно 1, но при изменении количества с помощью ф-ций plusGoods и minusGoods изменения происходят только в консоле, а в переменной val так и остается единица на странице.
Объясните пожалуйста, что я делаю не так и как устранить это проблему? 
Спасибо заранее

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы обновляете лишь значение переменной, а не DOM-дерево.
Можете добавить вспомогательную функцию и вызывать её после изменений, например:
`const updateGoodsCount = () => document.querySelector('div.val span').textContent = window.sum;`

Рабочий пример:

```js
var sum = 1;

const updateGoodsCount = () => document.querySelector('div.val span').textContent = sum; 

function goodsOut(data) {
  if (data != 0) {
    var pack = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}];
    console.log(pack);
    var out = "";
    out += `<div class="val-min" data-id="${pack.id}"><i class="fas fa-minus"></i></div>`;
    out += `<div class="val"><span>${sum}</span></div>`;
    out += `<div class="val-plus" data-id="${pack.id}" ><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></div>`;
  }
  $('.goods-out').html(out);
  $('.val-plus').on('click', plusGoods);
  $('.val-min').on('click', minusGoods);
}

function plusGoods() {
  var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
  sum++;
  updateGoodsCount();
  console.log(sum);
}

function minusGoods() {
  var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
  sum--;
  updateGoodsCount();
  console.log(sum);
}

goodsOut(2);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="goods-out">q</div>
<div class="val-plus">+</div>
<div class="val-min">-</div>
```

Comment: спасибо большое, это работает